# GIT installation in AIX 7.1

Tags: git, aix

I am trying to install GIT in AIX 7.1 machine getting below error

```
**# git
Could not load program git:
Symbol resolution failed for /usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) because:
        Symbol _GLOBAL__AIXI_shr_o (number 2) is not exported from dependent
          module /opt/freeware/lib/libgcc_s.a(shr.o).
        Symbol _GLOBAL__AIXD_shr_o (number 3) is not exported from dependent
          module /opt/freeware/lib/libgcc_s.a(shr.o).
System error: Error 0
Examine .loader section symbols with the 'dump -Tv' command.**
```

Could any one help me fix this issue.

Thanks,
Muthu

Comment: As a start: do you actually have a `/usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)` module? (Mind you, `/opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)` is perfectly okay.) Check with this command: `ar -X32_64 tv /usr/lib/libiconv.a`

Comment: Thanks for your reply  Lorinczy, Yes, libiconv.a is present.

# ar -X32_64 tv /usr/lib/libiconv.a
rwxr-xr-x  3262/1     1115895 May 21 11:04 2020 libiconv.so.2
rwxr-xr-x  3262/1     1142389 May 21 11:03 2020 libiconv.so.2
r--r--r--     0/0     237515 Aug 20 12:13 2020 shr4.o
r--r--r--     0/0     237637 Aug 20 12:13 2020 shr.o
r--r--r--     0/0     310177 Aug 20 12:13 2020 shr4_64.o

Comment: Your `/usr/lib/libiconv.a` might have been overwritten, but its new content is not compatible with your `/opt/freeware/lib/libgcc_s.a`. You should consult your sys-admin.